# Multiple pages VITE config, not converting classNames in HTML into hashed classNames

Tags: build, config, vite, css-modules

I need some help with Vite.config. I use twig plugin to collect all html templates in my entry point. Also, I connect .ts file to index.html as a module, where I import all my styles.

Everything builds nice except one thing - index.css in my dist folder has hashed classNames like Block_element_1Hd4sad, but in my index.html classes look like unhashed - Block_element.
I tried to use css.module setting in Vite, but no happyEnd found!

Here below is my Vite config:

```
const defineEntryAndChunkPaths = (chunkInfo) => {
  const initialPath = chunkInfo.facadeModuleId.split('!').pop().split(/[\\|\/]/g)
  const initialPathArray = initialPath.slice(initialPath.lastIndexOf('pages'), initialPath.length - 1)

  return initialPathArray.concat('js/[name].[hash].js').join('/')
}

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "components"),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "styles"),
      templates: path.resolve(__dirname, "templates"),
      scripts: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    twig({
      root: path.resolve(process.cwd()),
      namespaces: {
        "templates": path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'templates'),
        "pages": path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pages')
      },
      filetypes: {
        html: /.(twig.json|twig.json.html|twig|twig.html|html)$/,
      },
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(), react(),
  ],
  css: {
    modules: {
      scopeBehaviour: 'global',
      generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:2]'
    },
    postcss: {
      syntax: postcssScss,
      plugins: [
        postcssImport(),
        autoprefixer(),
      ],
    },
  },
  publicDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: false,
    target: "es2015",
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "some/nested/folder/index.html"),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: defineEntryAndChunkPaths,
        chunkFileNames: defineEntryAndChunkPaths,
        assetFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
          const entryName = chunkInfo.name;

          if (entryName.includes('.css')) {
            return "some/nested/folder/styles/[name].[ext]";
          } else {
            return "some/nested/folder/static/[name].[ext]";
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I tried to use postCss plugins and css.module in Vite

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: '../build',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        cssCodeSplit: true
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: {
                'js/app': 'resources/js/app.build.js',
                
                /*******************************START theme-name*********************************************/
                'frontend/theme-name/general': 'resources/assets/frontend-themes/theme-name/js/build/common.build.js',
                'frontend/theme-name/bootstrap': 'resources/assets/frontend-themes/theme-name/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'frontend/theme-name/cart.css': 'resources/assets/frontend-themes/theme-name/css/cart.css',
                /*******************************END theme-name*********************************************/
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                  // assetInfo.facadeModuleId contains the file's full path
                  if (assetInfo.facadeModuleId) {
                    const assetPath = path.dirname(assetInfo.facadeModuleId).replace(rootDir, '');
                    return assetPath + '/[name]-[hash].js';
        
                  } else {
                    return 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js';
                  }
                },
              },
            refresh: true,
        }),

        commonjs(),
        nodeResolve()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')
        }
    },
});
```